# Windows: Search through file contents except images

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-search

I need to search for the string `60` in some files. Many of these files are images. Is there a way to exclude by file extension while searching in windows explorer?

Or I suppose there's a way with powershell with `ls -Recurse` but that feels bad to me...

Comment: Also, why does windows keep sending me back up to the beginning of the search results when I'm halfway scrolling through them... :arg_face:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excluding an extension is easy enough in **Explorer**. In the **Search** box, type: `extension:NOT .jpg`

Is that strinfg part of the name or content? Is it separated from adjacent text by spaces or other non-alpha-numeric characters or is it butried: ...4603...? Try adding: 
`name:60` or 
`name:~"*60*"` or 
`content:60` to your extension criteria:
[image]

### [image]

Comment: I can't figure out how to follow these instructions because the taskbar is on the wrong side of the screen. JK, thanks. I didn't know about most of those.

Comment: What about the `Search` bar in **Explorer**?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing something like:

```
ls -Recurse -Exclude '*.png','*.jpg','*.jpeg' | sls 60
```

With a lot of other rigamarole thrown in to exclude directories, etc.

Comment: Exclude directories with the `-FIle` parameter: `gci -file -recurse ...`

Comment: Thanks, that's way better than my `? { Is-Directory $_ }` shenanigans...

Comment: You welcome. I went with the Explorer answer because you seemdd to imply **PowerShell** was less desirable. Don't know how familiar you are with it, but I've made an effort to learn it & really like it. There's great documentation, but consistency, tab-completion, `.GetType()`, and `Get-Member` make it easy to "play" and learn through discovery. But it's good to take the time to watch the MS video series:    [Getting Started with PowerShell](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/GetStartedPowerShell3). They'll give you an unparalleled grasp of the fundamentals that will serve you well.